# Make command in go-ethereum installation?

Tags: go, blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum

i am trying to change the source code of geth and I have some doubts.
I need to modify the following sentence in order to admit transactions with more data in them: `txMaxSize = 4 * txSlotSize // 128KB`
of tx_pool.go file: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/tx_pool.go
I have run

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.git
```

My doubt is whether i have to modify the file before or after running `make geth`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the perspective of building the application, you can simply:

```
git clone $repo
```

Make modifications to the file. Then

```
make geth
```

or

```
cd cmd/geth/
go build
```

to build your application. Just running `go build` will generally be faster for development / testing, but `make geth` gives more reproducible builds.

I would warn you though, that unless your plan is to make your own network with a separate client that has larger transactions, building Geth with larger transactions will just mean you can create transactions that won't propagate across the network very successfully as other nodes on the network will reject them. Most miners use Geth (or Geth forks) to assemble new blocks, and changing the parameters yourself won't change it for other nodes on the network.

Comment: Thanks for yout answer! Do you know if there is another way of allowing bigger data in transactions rather than changing source code?

Comment: You might look into Flashbots and MEV solutions - they may allow for longer transactions, but I can't say for sure. The other option would be to work with miners to make sure they'll include your transaction, or figure out how to break it up into multiple.